# What are the consequences for taking out General Oraka?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Toward the tail end of the *Aria: Blue Suns* mission, you're given the choice of either hunting down some rare artifacts or ordering a hit on General Oraka. **Besides the Renegade shift, are there any other consequences for placing a kill order on Oraka?** That is, is the story or gameplay changed in some way further down the line in the game because of this decision?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will fail to gain the War Asset Black Market Artifacts.  You will gain some renegade points.

Subsequently War Asset #27 – Terminus Fleet 2 will become unavailable since Oraka won't be around to prod you for it.